# Remove noglob from $@ variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, wildcards, ksh

I want to pass an argument to the shell script but I am getting `noglob on` as an output argument.

**a.sh**

```
#!/bin/ksh
set filec on
set noglob on
echo $@
```

When I run the shell script with an argument as 123, I am getting an output as below instead of 123. Even I have tried `unset noglob` and `set noglob off` but still I am getting the same output. Please help me to overcome this.

```
@sh a.sh 123 
noglob on
```

Comment: There’s also a missing bang on the she-bang line.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Corrected it. But same output... :-(

Comment: How were you able to edit that but not fix the noglob line that muru pointed out?

Answer (score 3):

I think you intended to do:

```
set -o filec
set -o noglob
```

`set` without any of the options sets the arguments as the shell's parameters. From [`man mksh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mksh.1.html):

> Options can be changed using the +-o *option* syntax, where option is
>   the long name of an option, or using the +-*letter* syntax, where *letter*
>   is the option's single letter name (not all options have a single
>   letter name).

(But I can't find a shell option named `filec` in `mksh`, at least.)

Comment: Actually this `set noglob on` is present in a read only source file. So I cannot edit that file. If I use that file in my shell script then I am getting this output.

Comment: Then you'll have to copy whatever useful content you want from the read-only file to your script. This is `set`'s behaviour in most shells and you won't be able to change that easily.

Comment: Also note that the script is invoked with `sh` explicitly (if `@` is the shell prompt in the question).

Answer (score 2):

When using `set` the way you do in a `sh-`like shell:

```
set noglob on
```

you actually modify `$@` by replacing the arguments given on the command line with `noglob` and `on` (as if you had invoked the script with `sh a.sh noglob on`).

To set the shell option `noglob`, use

```
set -o noglob
```

Neither `sh` nor `ksh` has a shell option called `filec`, as far as I know.

Note that if you invoke the script with an explicit interpreter like `sh`, the `#!`-line will be ignored.

---

Since your script looks like either a `tcsh` or `csh` script (the `set` syntax is absolutely correct and these shells also has a `filec` shell option, but the `$@` variable is not in `csh` as far as I know):

*If* it's a `csh` or `tcsh` script you are writing, then make sure that you invoke the script with either `csh` or `tcsh` or, if the script is executable and invoked without an explicit interpreter, that the `#!` line points to the appropriate one of these two.

In short, make sure you know what language you are writing your script in and use the correct interpreter.